# Moving a random item between two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to take a random item from `dict2` and add it to `dict1`:

```
import random
dict1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
dict2 = {'c':3,'d':4}

dict1 += random.choice(dict2.items)
print(dict1)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\64221\Desktop\dict_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    dict1 += random.choice(dict2.items)
  File "C:\Users\64221\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py", line 288, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
>>>
```

Comment: Missing `()` on `.items` -> `.items()`

Comment: Also `+=` with a random item (e.g. `('c', 3)`) won't work and you can't make a `random.choice` from a `dict_items` object anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems indicated in comments:

- You don't actually **call** `items`. It should be: `random.choice(dict2.items())`
- `dict2.items()` returns a `dict_items` object which does not support indexing and can't be used in `random.choice`.
- You can't use `+=` between a `dict` and a `tuple` (which is what `items()` holds).

A slightly different approach is to chose a random ***key***, and add it to `dict1` with its corresponding value from `dict2`:

```py
import random

dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
dict2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}

key = random.choice(list(dict2.keys()))
dict1[key] = dict2[key]
```

Note the use of `list(dict2.keys())` (which can also just be `list(dict2)`). This is because similarly to [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), [`keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) returns a `dict_keys` object which does not support indexing, so in order to use `random.choice` we have to make it into a list first.

---

If you want to **move** the item, meaning ***remove** from `dict1` and add to `dict2`*, just change to:

```
dict1[key] = dict2.pop(key)
```

Using dicts' [`pop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) method.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I'm trying to move a random item...", do you mean, pick a random item from `dict1`, remove it from `dict1` and insert it into `dict2`?

```
from random import choice

d1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
d2 = {}

key = choice(tuple(d1))
value = d1.pop(key)

d2.update({key: value})

print(d1)
print(d2)
```

Output:

```
{'b': 2, 'c': 3}
{'a': 1}
>>>
```